# Set screen resolution with command line at win 8 or blue?

Tags: windows-8, command-line, windows-8.1, resolution

Is any body know how to set screen resolution from command line, at win 8 or 8.1?

and how to do it to projector I mean another display?

Thanks
Hagay

Answer (score 0):

`Get-DisplayResolution` and `Set-DisplayResolution` will work for setting a screen resolution in poewrshell, but I have no secondary screen or projector to test how it handles multiple displays.

Comment: Set-DisplayResolution is on Server only.